# Putting set of text files with .log extension into an R dataset and including filename as element of record

Tags: r, filenames

I generate a set of text files with a `.csv` extension named `001.csv`, `002.csv`, etc. `001.csv` has a single value of 30000 and the `002.csv` has a value of 10000 as an example.
I need these within an R data set and I need the first three digits of the filename to be the column name. Typically there is only one numeric value in each file.

I tried using the advice [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092102/how-can-i-turn-the-filename-into-a-variable-when-reading-multiple-csvs-into-r) but not very successfully.

I tried the following:

```
Filenames <- dir(pattern = "0*")
```

This gave for `head(Filenames)`:

```
"001.csv" "002.csv" "003.csv" "004.csv"

z <- read.zoo(files, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

This provides the following:

```
z

Data:

numeric(0)

Index:

integer(0)
```

What I was looking for was something like this:

```
001.csv     002.csv   

30000        10000
```

I use R infrequently at long intervals so some advice would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
files <- list.files('/path/to/your/dir') # list all
files <- files[grep('*.csv',files)] # only csv files

dat <- do.call(cbind, lapply(files, read.csv)) # guessing, can't test
names(dat) <- substr(files,1,3) # rename with first 3 digits
```

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the quick response. I ran this in Rstudio on an Ubuntu desktop. You could try this by just creating two text files 001.csv and 002.csv. After running this dat just contains 001 and 002  as headers but no data below  it. Not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFiles = list.files(path="~/Desktop/data", pattern="*.csv")
Lapply <- lapply(myFiles, read.csv, header=FALSE)
names(Lapply) <- myFiles
for(i in myFiles) 
  Lapply[[i]]$Source = i
answer <- do.call(rbind, Lapply)
```

This was derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092102/how-can-i-turn-the-filename-into-a-variable-when-reading-multiple-csvs-into-r?lq=1)